# Can datasets with different format(.jpeg and .tif) be used together for training a CNN

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am currently having medical images from two sources. One is having JPEG format while other is having TIF format, TIF format is lossless while JPEG is lossy so if I convert TIF to JPEG there is a chance of data loss or can I mix both together and use it for training the CNN.
Using Keras with Tensorflow backend.

Comment: depends on how you read the images. Tensorflow will use decoded images anyways, so their used format (like 3 channel 32 bit floating point images) will be identical anyways. Lossy compression might be a problem or not, depends on your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural networks, and Machine Learning models in general, do not take specific file formats as input, but expect matrices/tensors of real numbers as input. For RGB images this means a tensor with dimensions (width, height, 3). When the image is read from a file, its transformed automatically into a tensor, so it does not matter which kind of file format you use.